# Is it possible to have rest parameters with repeating types?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out if I can write a type-safe function that accepts a repeating varargs parameter. For example, it accepts 1+ pairs of `string`, `number`. Here's how you would call it:

```
declare function repeatingRestParamsPairs(...args: unknown[] /* What type should I use here? */): void;

repeatingRestParamsPairs(); // error
repeatingRestParamsPairs("a"); // error
repeatingRestParamsPairs("a", 1); // compiles
repeatingRestParamsPairs("a", 1, "b"); // error
repeatingRestParamsPairs("a", 1, "b", 2); // compiles
repeatingRestParamsPairs("a", 1, "b", 2, "c"); // error
repeatingRestParamsPairs("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3); // compiles
```

Inside the implementation of `repeatingRestParams`, `args[oddNumber]` would be `string`. `args[evenNumber]` would be `number`.

Please note that I'm only using pairs of `string` and `number` for illustrative purposes. Ideally, the solution would allow triples and longer repeating patterns. It would also allow interfaces, union types, and intersection types to be used as a type in the repeating pattern, e.g.:

```
type FirstInPattern = "a" | "b" | "c" // the first in the pattern should be one of these

declare function repeatingRestParamsTriple(...args: unknown[] /* What type should I use here? */): void;

repeatingRestParamsTriple(); // error
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a"); // error
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a", 1); // error
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a", 1, 2); // compiles
repeatingRestParamsTriple("foo", 1, 2); // error
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a", 1, 2, "b"); // error
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a", 1, 2, "b", 3); // error
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a", 1, 2, "b", 3, 4); // compiles
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a", 1, 2, "b", 3, 4, "c"); // error
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a", 1, 2, "b", 3, 4, "c", 5); // error
repeatingRestParamsTriple("a", 1, 2, "b", 3, 4, "c", 5, 6); // compiles
```

I've done a lot of research on this and I can't figure out if this is possible; it's like trying to prove a negative. The closest thing I've found are [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), but I don't see any examples of repeating patterns.

I've also tried changing `...args: unknown[]` to `...args: [argType1, argType2]`. That expands to function that accepts exactly two parameters. And `...args: [argType1, argType2][]` expands to a function that takes a variadic number of `[argType1, argType2]` as parameters; I want `argType1, argType2, argType1?, argType2?, ...` as parameters. Is this possible?

Comment: Pretty sure we encountered this exact problem before... now I gotta spend half an hour finding the q/a...

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You could write a bunch of overloads but that wouldn't allow an arbitrary length. It wouldn't be much fun to _use_ anyway, the array of tuples makes more sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "It wouldn't be much fun to use anyway, the array of tuples makes more sense." While that may be true, this is an example of defining types on legacy js code, so this is the real way to use it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe BTW, I'm confused about your edit, especially the removal of the tags. Can you explain?

Comment: @zenly re: your second reply, in other words, arguably those tags should be removed from the site?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMzozW) meet your needs?  If so I'm happy to write up an answer to the question explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That works great when it comes to calling it, but in the implementation `args[2+]` is `never`. [Is that because I am accessing `args` incorrectly?](https://tsplay.dev/w6pdGm)

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I may have worded it poorly, but that is what I was trying to say in the second sentence: "Inside the implementation of `repeatingRestParams`, `args[oddNumber]` would be string. `args[evenNumber]` would be number."

Comment: @jcalz But if the implementation requires casting, I'd accept your code and that note as an answer, but would you show me the best way to access those `2+` elements in your answer? Would that be casting?

Comment: Yeah, you’d need type assertions (what you’re calling “casting”) or something like it.

Comment: @jcalz ah, shame. Okay I'll accept that as an answer. BTW, are you aware of anything on the typescript roadmap that could avoid these type assertions in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *specific* type in TypeScript corresponding to all [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) formed by concatenating a particular tuple together some arbitrary positive number of times.  If you have some reasonably small maximum number of repetitions you want to support, you can write a utility type to assemble an appropriate [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
type RepeatUpTo<T extends any[], N extends number, A extends any[][] = [T]> =
  A['length'] extends N ? A[number] : RepeatUpTo<T, N, [[...A[0], ...T], ...A]>

type Demo = RepeatUpTo<[0, 1, 2], 4>
// type Demo = [0, 1, 2] | [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2] | [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2] | 
//  [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2];
```

And then for, say, `[string, number]`, you could write `repeatingChunk()` like:

```
type Chunk = [string, number];
declare function repeatingChunk(...args: RepeatUpTo<Chunk, 10>): void;
```

which works for all your examples

```
repeatingChunk(); // error
repeatingChunk("a"); // error
repeatingChunk("a", 1); // compiles
repeatingChunk("a", 1, "b"); // error
repeatingChunk("a", 1, "b", 2); // compiles
repeatingChunk("a", 1, "b", 2, "c"); // error
repeatingChunk("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3); // compiles
```

but fails if you exceed the arbitrarily chosen maximum number of repetitions above:

```
repeatingChunk("", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 
  0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0); // error! 
// Source has 22 element(s) but target allows only 20.
```

So it depends on your use case; do you really need to support *arbitrarily many* repetitions?  Oh, as for the implementation, there's some good news and some bad news:

```
function repeatingChunk(...args: RepeatUpTo<Chunk, 10>) { {
  args[0].toUpperCase(); // 
  args[1].toFixed(); // 
  args[2]?.toUpperCase(); // 
  args[3]?.toFixed(); // 
  args[19]?.toFixed(); // 
  args[20]?.toUpperCase(); // 
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length / 2; i++) {
    args[2 * i].toUpperCase(); // 
    args[2 * i + 1].toFixed(); // 
  }
}
```

While the compiler is aware that *specific* even and odd indices have `string` and `number` (or `undefined`) values, it doesn't know how to generalize that to any loop-like code.  The type system isn't performing the higher order analysis on math to know that `2 * i` will be even and that even indices less than the length have `string` values.  So even in this best-possible case where the compiler knows a lot about the input, you'd still need [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to proceed.

```
for (let i = 0; i < args.length / 2; i++) {
  (args[2 * i] as string).toUpperCase();
  (args[2 * i + 1] as number).toFixed();
}
```

---

Anyway, if you really do need to support *arbitrarily many* repetitions, you'll have to give up on a specific type and instead write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, and make `repeatingChunk` a generic function.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type Chunk = [string, number];
type _Repeating<T> = T extends [...Chunk, ...infer R] ?
  [string, number, ..._Repeating<R>] : [];
type Repeating<T> = [...Chunk, ...any[]] & _Repeating<T>

declare function repeatingChunk<T extends any[]>(
  ...args: T extends Repeating<T> ? T : Repeating<T>): void;
```

Here `Repeating<T>` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that verifies `T` to be a valid concatenation of copies of `Chunk`.

The type of `args` is `T extends Repeating<T> ? T : Repeating<T>`, which looks weird, but is being used to guide inference.  Ideally we'd want to constrain `T extends Repeating<T>`, but that doesn't work because it's a circular constraint.  Then you might want to make `args` of type `Repeating<T>`, but this also doesn't work (try it and see).  One technique I've used is to infer from an inlined conditional type of the form `T extends F<T> ? T : F<T>`.  The compiler looks at `T extends ⋯` and infers `T` from the type of the function parameter (in this case it's the `args` rest parameter).  It then *checks* it against `T extends F<T> ? T : F<T>`.  If it succeeds, then this is equivalent to `T` and it continues to succeed. If it fails, then this is equivalent to `F<T>` and it continues to fail. I don't know that this technique is officially documented anywhere; it's just another one of the annoying things you can do when inferring generics from these complicated conditional types.

Let's see if it works:

```
repeatingChunk(); // error
repeatingChunk("a"); // error
repeatingChunk("a", 1); // compiles
repeatingChunk("a", 1, "b"); // error
repeatingChunk("a", 1, "b", 2); // compiles
repeatingChunk("a", 1, "b", 2, "c"); // error
repeatingChunk("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3); // compiles
```

That's good... and it still works for longer argument lists:

```
repeatingChunk("", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 
  0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0, "", 0); // compiles
```

So this works for arbitrarily long input lists... from the caller's side.

The implementation continues to have problems, and they are even more noticeable.  Now only the `0` and `1` indices are strongly-typed.  The rest are inferred to be of type `never`, because the compiler is really bad at analyzing generic conditional types:

```
function repeatingChunk<T extends any[]>(
  ...args: T extends Repeating<T> ? T : Repeating<T>) {
  args[0].toUpperCase(); // 
  args[1].toFixed(); // 
  args[2]?.toUpperCase(); // 
  args[3]?.toFixed(); // 
  args[19]?.toFixed(); // 
  args[20]?.toUpperCase(); // 
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length / 2; i++) {
    args[2 * i].toUpperCase(); // 
    args[2 * i + 1].toFixed(); // 
  }
}
```

So here too, you'd need to use type assertions to make progress inside the function:

```
for (let i = 0; i < args.length / 2; i++) {
  (args[2 * i] as string).toUpperCase();
  (args[2 * i + 1] as number).toFixed();
}
```

There might be some approaches that could make the implementation less painful, but they will all involve some loss of type safety.  The only way I could imagine this improving is if TypeScript ever supports "repeating tuple" types natively, which is unlikely... *as well as* a way to distribute them into strongly-typed chunks (or understand the math of `2*i+1`), which is even more unlikely.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAKUWANgLxQb2CJRXGniVQAUBLRAawFkwAPGiAVwgOJJQBcAnnFQAlKCLD8AqnAAqAewA8clFBb8oIACYwUYEIIDaAXQA0KAHJqNW3aS4AjKACcLAQRuadeg8ZOmKAC8KEZyJgB8wcB8fO5GAORYWgDm-AAWCSZednrWAPwo8SBOrtkAXCjikjLyynIWlhZGRgB07fEADOYo7a3hFn3ukbwkQiIoACJQEArBVRJQUrKKSkadFgCMFgBMPQAsETF8APQnAsKo07Pz61u72QA+oRso2yg7Fq-veyjPd29dl97h9gYCPk8UMcSGcSACfmCEShvkDkSC9gBuUYXCYAYXSHBA9FuMH4LhoIBSFhKEGcLhMWNiADNCYh+DQFCAUC5FlIKSl8YT6AAKPpgFwpGCVapLWqrQVEradCIASh4sRI4sl6xMrX4ClkIhcuLAMCgwpVGJQsMAvBuAWR3oXwtTAjJtdfqAGI0FhQbQWq22h0a-QSl17fJ6g1wI0ms3+63ne2OzWhowAZhMEc93t98cDyZD2s2AE5M5GvT6-ZaEygk8HnUYdt0s1GY6bzdXbYA5HYLTIULhQwuS-BQNHmnStY6UhZgrWSlIy1o+k4A1Cu1YRgyntTsUAAqUfu1uuWMdgOJntbmeN-ejlArt5Hiu5zsXgsAX17-cHw7vIQnd7Ts6c6pIu5w7Ku67qluwoNruB40NkpooKS5KUiqkaGie7b+gWJCwam8F3g+br6HoNJ0hh2aVrhwafrEn6OjyNT8gqIqvmoLguP2TG8uylJscKABEYBCRxrjcS4vEsQJBJEsJolbBxiAKBAcA0MkMDSbKrFySKIlCSCQmOGJ56cZJ2l8rJQoKYZ4LGXZOzKap6maZZ-ECnptlGSZqJCYgpk1hJPGxMxOnWfJBk+Y5Fj+XZabOWpGmwNiYVWZ5NlCXZrxZWCuVoig+U5dlsUlYVZVFaVeUVdl4lcf2ACEtaAER7jqwgAygoHAuMgKDpMhOy7lAyTQCA-DCjAaqOBwI78FqUAjtgWAKAA7nonJYIIHydK0RDHIxJBkLACC9QA4lorh0DwjrjKgAD6MrpSoUQhKo6jePYbTtGxgztBSTKuFU2T5AWRiofy1KlG4vTtA9fH8koogRBUoQMjdlwLDJKTPbcfQ-TDrR+KY2QAGQoHDWPPdit0oGxJJkhDDi0mUjJ8CyIBshyXJpR5bEqDkPj6IYpgRKK7TOpUb22ILj0eTjhSqNK8OUs9G4Fg23SYdG2FxhxdYag2brljmVZmfrsRwWW+pYcaOF65eBuphmLbPqbNY2g7FupiWVsKK7eZvvWhHNlrba62bnts9+Q4LX+yKTigQGhiBC7pEuEGjmuatXnBt6IaHOtnu7kdezuef3o+xs0fbH5fgOMcjmO-4J0nkop2kafgZB2cwbnCFIXo4PoQXtvh3hg598Rj5kUzlFVy+rMMY6B18Dzuk2XVFmhcrGWRaJm8havO+CVFbyJa5KXb1jJ+KfZJkH1JV-hbv+m3+8Dm7OfyVaU-6U33Z79fKgkKgFB+7l157wAbFIBnwQHxS-m5X+vMvKVXKtVdBBVUFYJqhg4quCEGXxQIxYA74gA)

Comment: Thank you this is great. I'm new to advanced types and I hadn't considered using `A['length']` in recursive types, so that opens new possibilities for me. I have a few minor questions: 1) is there any particular reason you used `any` instead of `unknown`? 2) I understand `_Repeating` but `Repeating` confuses me a bit. In `[...Chunk, ...any[]] & _Repeating<T>`, what is the `...any[]` and the `&` achieving? I suspect this relates to having **1 or more** varargs? 3) Why does `repeatingChunk` have `<T extends any[]>` I don't understand the `...args` type. Honestly I don't understand `args` at all.

Comment: oh and 4) I noticed `repeatingChunk` in the `Generic` namespace doesn't handle union types the way I would expect. Here's what happens when I define `Chunk` as `type Chunk = ["a" | "b" | "c" | "", number];` in both name spaces: https://tsplay.dev/wOlo6N Would you be able to explain what causes that issue? Thanks again

Comment: 1: I use `any` in constraints instead of `unknown` if I don't want to worry about variance; feel free to change to `unknown` if it works for you. 2) Yes, you want to disallow zero-length args and that was the easiest way for me to do it 3) Is that two questions?  `T extends any[]` is so the compiler knows that the args will be arraylike and not complain. The `...args` type is a conditional check; it infers `T` from the arg list, and then checks against the type to validate it. I'll need more to go on than "I don't understand it at all" unless you want a book-length reply.

Comment: 4: It's not a union-issue, it's a string literal type issue; the compiler isn't getting the hint that it should infer the 3rd-through-nth arguments as literal types; it just infers `string` and that makes it fail.  If you `as const` each argument or copy from an existing literal type variable [it works](//tsplay.dev/WG8Dkw) (not that this is convenient)   I'm not prepared to dive into fixing that since inference is fiddly and I haven't seen a convincing use case for why you don't just use the maximum-length-of-N for some particular N approach.  Does that address your followup questions?

Comment: I think 3) turned out to be two questions but I didn't realize that until your answer. `I'll need more to go on than "I don't understand it at all" unless you want a book-length reply.` Yeah, apologies for that. I think I can be *slightly* more precise now I've read your answer: Where can I learn more about, `it infers T from the arg list, and then checks against the type to validate it.`? e.g., why wouldn't it infer if the `...args` type were only `Repeating<T>`? When would `T extends Repeating<T>` be true or false? When false, why would you evaluate `Repeating<T>` again? etc.

Comment: `Does that address your followup questions?` That answered 1, 2, and 4 for me. Are my follow-up questions for 3) out of scope? I have a lot of unknown unknowns re: 3. I'm not really sure what I would ask in a separate SO post. If there is a link to relevant documentation or specific terms I could research, I would consider everything answered. Thanks again!

Comment: I added a paragraph explaining as best I can; there is no official documentation about that technique, and I'm not sure what to tell you in terms of search terms... "conditional generic type inference" maybe?  Anyway, if I were to spell that out in detail and go over all the possible ways to infer or fail to infer it would be quite the digression, so I hope it's okay to stop there.

Comment: That's awesome. I'm new to all this stuff so even knowing that this is a rather obscure/undocumented technique is valuable information. You've gone above and beyond in your answer already. Once again, thank you!